# Upload imagem Base64 to S3 from Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, amazon-s3

I trying to send an imagem base64 to s3 using angular, with react works with the endpoint of the backend but in angular gives me an error:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Backend is simple:

```
s3.getSignedUrl(
    'putObject',
    {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        Key: key
    },
    (e, url) => res.send({ key, url })
);
```

Then on angular I have 2 services:

```
uploadImage(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${api}/upload`).toPromise();
}

saveImage(url: string, image): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(url, image, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Encoding': 'base64' },
    });}
```

That I call them in this way in my component:

```
this.service.uploadImage().then(({ url }) => {
                this.service
                    .saveImage(url, this.webcamImage.imageAsBase64)
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        console.log(res);
                    });
            });
```

The imagem that i trying to pass is a imagem captured by [ngx-webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam)

Regards!

Comment: what is the signed signature version that you are using?? I see you have not defined it here....

Comment: the signature is returned in url generated by the service "uploadImage", that i made the put

Comment: here an exemple that url return: https://XXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/XXXX/XXXXXX.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXX&Content-Encoding=base64&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1584038582&Signature=XXXXXX

Comment: try adding this `signatureVersion: 'v4'` configuration in your s3 object configuration

Comment: {Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
   ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
   ContentEncoding: 'base64',
   Key: key,
   signatureVersion: 'v4' }, here?

Comment: const s3 = new AWS.S3({
 secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
 accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
 region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
 signatureVersion: 'v4'
}); doesn't work too